# How to build Conversational IVR with microsoftbot framework using Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-click-to-call

I want to connect Microsoft chatbot to twilio , whenever user makes a call to twilio number it internally needs to connect to Chat bot and return response to user via twilio .

How can i achieve this ?

I tried [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-twilio?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) but it only works for SMS but I want IVR bot

bot details - Deployed in Azure ,.net core(v4)

Comment: The link shows how to connect Twilio Voice & Messaging, this should give you IVR capabilities. What exactly is not working as expected?

Comment: i tried [this example](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/63.twilio-adapter/Bots/EchoBot.cs) ,, when i make call through Twilio number it says "application error"  and  Error - 11205 in twilio logs , i want IVR to detect what user says and repeat same

Comment: [Error 11205](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11205) points to a network connectivity issue, and looking at the link I see the voice hook for the TwiML being left blank. Looking at this [GitHub issue from the Bot Framework](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/2468) I think what you're trying to achieve is not possible out of the box. Best attempt is probably to use the voice hook to have a Twilio Function to do speech to text and deliver this back to your chatbot. But you might as well move to Twilio Autopilot then.